# Set up docker with PASS OpenPGP secret key

Tags: linux, docker, devops, cicd

Created a pipeline in azure devops. I have set up a docker on the server, in order to get an image, I need to log in. Further, due to the fact that the password in the docker during authorization is stored simply in an unprotected form, I configured the standard unix password manager(PASS). But then I got in, so that all automation took off, I need to enter the password after pass docker-credential-helper/docker-pass-initialized-check, but then I get this
[window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObOwM.png)

And how should I insert the password there?

Maybe there is some way out, I won't put my mind to it yet

I tried to insert it somehow with a script, but nothing came out